# Disable silent mode on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, silent

How do you disable the user from turning the phone on silent? (switching the switch on the top left of the phone?)

I want my app to always play sound no matter what the state of that switch is. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: With AVAudioPlayer it doesn't?

Comment: As an aside, disobeying my preferences is _instant_ cause for de-installation of an application - my devices belong to _me,_ not some self-important developer :-)

Comment: Unless your app is an alarm clock, please don't.

Comment: @paxdiablo : You should not have to de-install an app if it was properly documented and you read the description before installing it.  Different users have different needs.

Comment: it is an alarm clock, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please search stackoverflow or the web for similar questions before posting a new one, this question has already been covered:

[Play sound on iPhone even in silent mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode)

[iphone, how to play sound even in silent or mute mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749066/iphone-how-to-play-sound-even-in-silent-or-mute-mode)

Be careful about overriding the silent mode switch and playing audio. Apple may not like you doing this, depending on the context; if they don't like it, you will fail app review. Is there a good reason to play audio when in silent mode in the context of your app?

Comment: Yeah, it's necessary, sorry for the repeat question, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I have done that works great!

Set all your contacts Emergency By Pass OFF! Then decide who should break through by turning the Emergency By Pass ON to those important calls you simply can’t miss; Family members like Mom and Dad.

Now your all set to use he Silent switch.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I believe that the person asking the question is asking how to prevent an end-user from disabling silent mode/how to ignore the state of the silent mode switch using a code approach. This way, the application has the intended effect on all devices regardless of the end user's personal settings. Your answer is from the perspective of the end user, not the programmer.